# javascript (included in a jsp) isn't rendered

Tags: javascript, jsp, cytoscape-web

I'm trying to include javascript-tags into a jsp-file, but it isn't rendered..
The code looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="AC_OETags.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="json2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="cytoscapeweb.min.js"></script>  
    <script language="JavaScript">
        window.onload=function() {
                    // network data could alternatively be grabbed via ajax
             var xml = '\
            <graphml>\
            <key id="label" for="all" attr.name="label" attr.type="string"/>\
            <key id="weight" for="node" attr.name="weight" attr.type="double"/>\
            <graph edgedefault="undirected">\
                <node id="1"><data key="label">1</data><data key="weight">1.8</data></node>\
                <node id="2"><data key="label">2</data><data key="weight">1.1</data></node>\
                <node id="3"><data key="label">3</data><data key="weight">1.1</data></node>\
                <node id="4"><data key="label">4</data><data key="weight">1.1</data></node>\
                <node id="5"><data key="label">5</data><data key="weight">.3</data></node>\
                <node id="6"><data key="label">6</data><data key="weight">.3</data></node>\
                <edge source="1" target="2" ></edge>\
                <edge source="2" target="3" ></edge>\
                <edge source="4" target="5" ></edge>\
                <edge source="3" target="4" ></edge>\
                <edge source="6" target="5" ></edge>\
                <edge source="4" target="2" ></edge>\
                <edge source="6" target="1" ></edge>\
            </graph>\
            </graphml>\
            ';

                    // init and draw
                    // initialization options
                        var options = {
                            swfPath: "CytoscapeWeb",
                            flashInstallerPath: "playerProductInstall"
                        };

                        var vis = new org.cytoscapeweb.Visualization("cytoscapeweb", options);

                        var draw_options = {
                            // your data goes here
                            network: xml,

                            // show edge labels too
                            edgeLabelsVisible: false,

                            edgeTooltipsEnabled:true,

                            // let's try another layout
                            layout: "circle",

                            // hide pan zoom
                            panZoomControlVisible: true
                        };

                        vis.draw(draw_options);

                    };
    </script>

    <style>
        /* The Cytoscape Web container must have its dimensions set. */
        html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        #cytoscapeweb { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>The Graph</h1>
    <div id="cytoscapeweb">
         Cytoscape Web will replace the contents of this div with your graph.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It uses Cytoscape Web in order to render a graph.
If I run this from a normal html-file evereything works fine...

Any Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't rendered"? Does your html show up but the script isn't included? Does anything show up? Do you get an exception? In that case, did you check your server log?

Comment: I mean, that the graph is not printed. There's only the sentence "Cytoscape Web will replace the contents of this div with your graph." If I save the same file as a html-file, everything works, so are there some restrictions according to javascript combined with jsp-files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to include the links like that:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="<%@ include file="AC_OETags.min.js" %>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="<%@ include file="json2.min.js" %>"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="<%@ include file="cytoscapeweb.min.js" %>"></script>
```